# Show by induction that $(n^2) + 1 < 2^n$ for intergers $n > 4$

Tags: induction

So I know it's true for $n = 5$ and assumed true for some $n = k$ where $k$ is an interger greater than or equal to $5$.

for $n = k + 1$ I get into a bit of a kerfuffle.

I get down to $(k+1)^2 + 1 < 2^k + 2^k$ or equivalently:

$(k + 1)^2 + 1 < 2^k * 2$.

A bit stuck at how to proceed at this point

Comment: How did you arrive from inequality to equality? You have $k^2+1 < 2^k ,\, k>4$, you should prove $(k+1)^2+1<2^{k+1}$

Comment: Whoops, my mistake there. Meant an inequality sign

Answer (score 3):

$$2^{k+1}=2\left(2^k\right)>2(k^2+1)=2k^2+2=k^2+k^2+2\overset{(*)}>k^2+2k+2=(k^2+1)+1$$ So, it remains to show that $k^2>2k$ for $k>4$. But $$k^2-2k=k(k-2)>0$$ for all $k>2$.

Answer (score 0):

**First, show that this is true for $n=5$:**

$5^2+1<2^5$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$n^2+1<2^n$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$(n+1)^2+1=$

$n^2+\color\green{2}\cdot{n}+1+1<$

$n^2+\color\green{n}\cdot{n}+1+1=$

$n^2+n^2+1+1=$

$2\cdot(\color\red{n^2+1})<$

$2\cdot(\color\red{2^n})=$

$2^{n+1}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle
2^n = (1+1)^n > \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}>n^2+1
$
iff $n>5$. (*)

The case $n=5$ is proved by inspection.

(*) This seems to be a cubic inequality but it reduces to an easy quadratic.