# Prove using finite induction that $4^n > n^4$ for all $n > 4$?

Tags: inequality, induction

Well, $4^5 = 1024$ and $5^4 = 625$, so the statement certainly holds when n = 5. Suppose that for some integer k ≥ 5, the conclusion holds. That is

$4^k > k^4$.

Consider the case $n = k + 1$. Note that $4^{k+1} = 4 \cdot 4^k$. Also

$(k+1)^4 = k^4 + 4k^3 + 6k^2 + 4k + 1$.

Now $k ≥ 5$, so $4k^3 < k^4$, $6k^2 < k^4$, and $4k + 1 < k^4$. So

$$(k+1)^4 < 4\cdot k^4.$$

Can't go ahead of this.

Comment: Without induction, this follows from $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ being decreasing for $x>e$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove by induction that $n^2 \leq 2^n$ for all $n \geq 5$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675411/prove-by-induction-that-n2-2n-for-all-n-geq-5)

Comment: You can translate the proof directly  from the duplicate because $(n^2)^2 \leq (2^n)^2$ implies $n^4 \leq 4^n$ which means, equivalently $4^n\leq n^4$ for $n\gt 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just shown that $(k+1)^4 <4\cdot k^4$ and we know that, by the inductive hypothesis, $k^4 <4^k $ so we have $(k+1)^4 <4\cdot 4^k=4^{k+1} $ and we have completed the inductive step.

Comment: Can you solve it any other way but by induction, this really confuses me

Comment: If you know calculus there is a simple non induction proof.

Comment: I have to do it by finite induction only